# How do I handle cookie accept button within nested iframes in selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I've tried almost everything and searched on SO but can't get passed the cookie accept on gmx.com. Hoping someone can help out. So far I've tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEPATH)
driver.get('https://www.gmx.com')
time.sleep(5)
cookie_accept = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')))
cookie_accept.click()
```

===AND===

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEPATH)
driver.get('https://www.gmx.com')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[style='onetrust-style'] button[id*='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[style='onetrust-style'] button[id*='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']").click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

What am I doing wrong?! Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Agree and continue</kbd> is within nested  elements so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **parent** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the **child** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.gmx.com/consentpage")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.permission-core-iframe")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://plus.gmx.com/lt']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.gmx.com/consentpage")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='permission-core-iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://plus.gmx.com/lt')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: GMX]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: You should define a `wait` object only once, not 3 times.

Comment: WOW THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @Prophet _You should define a wait object only once, not 3 times_ : Where are you coming from? Any documentation to support your comment? Why would the _GC_ mechanism implemented?

Comment: @DebanjanB I don't know about official documentation about this. I just know that I wrote an answer like this with several initializations of wait object and some other user with quite wrote me that this is not the correct way. It also seems to me to be logically correct

Answer (score 1):

This element is inside an iframe. iframe inside iframe. So you have to switch to the inner iframe in order to access that element.
Something like this:

```py
driver.get("https://www.gmx.com/consentpage")  
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.permission-core-iframe")))  
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src,'plus')]")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]'))).click()
```